# How do you use images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a page with multiple products with each a title, description, etc. I have all of that in a JSON-file.

```json
{
    "limoncello": {
        "title": "Limoncello Artigianale Fattorie Cilentane, Liquore di Limoni 30°",
        "description": "Het is een bijzondere voorstelling van een Limoncello, vanwege het originele recept die nog steeds gebruikt wordt. De herkomst, de zorgvuldige selectie en de daaropvolgende verwerking van de citroenen is te vinden in zijn onmiskenbaar geur. Bij het drinken laat het verspreiden van de aroma een aangenaam en onvergetelijke smaak achter.",
        "afkomst": "Campania, Italië",
        "producent": "Fattorie Cilentale",
        "formaten": "20cl, 50cl, 70cl, 100cl & 200cl",
        "imgsrc": "../img/limoncello.png" <---- IMPORTANT
    },
    "proseccobrut": {
        "title": ...
        ...
    }
}
```

This is my component for each product
Product.jsx

```
import "../css/app.css";
import "../css/general.css";

const data = require("../productData.json");

const Product = ({ item }) => {
    const DisplayData = data[item];
    return (
        <section>
            <div className="center">
                <img src={require(DisplayData.imgsrc)} alt={DisplayData.title} /> <---- IMPORTANT
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>{DisplayData.title}</h1>
                <h3>Over dit product</h3>
                <p>{DisplayData.description}</p>
                <h4>Regio van afkomst</h4>
                <p>{DisplayData.afkomst}</p>
                <h4>Producent</h4>
                <p>{DisplayData.producent}</p>
                <h4>{DisplayData.formaten.length > 5 ? "Formaten" : "Formaat"}</h4>
                <p>{DisplayData.formaten}</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

And here's my App.jsx

```
// components
import Product from "./components/product";
import Hero from "./components/hero";

// css
import "./css/app.css";
import "./css/general.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <main className="products">
        <Product item="limoncello" />
        <Product item="proseccobrut" />
        <Product item="proseccoextradry" />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here's my document tree

```
.
├── App.jsx
├── components
│   ├── hero.jsx
│   └── product.jsx
├── css
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── general.css
│   └── index.css
├── img
│   ├── Producten.jpg
│   ├── limoncello.png
│   ├── logo.png
│   ├── pesto.png
│   ├── proseccoBrut.png
│   ├── proseccoExtraDry.png
│   ├── proseccoTreviso.png
│   └── roseNoir.png
├── index.js
└── productData.json
```

And the console
[image: in-browser console]

I used to have a prop `imgsrc` and in this was done in app.js `<Product item="limoncello" imgsrc="{require("./img/limoncello.png")}` and it worked.

Comment: remove `require()` in img src

Comment: you can image url as just as it. `img` element supports to read from url

Answer (score 1):

First try removing `require` from `img src`. If that doesn't work then try using below code.

Try importing your `images` on top in your `product.jsx` like below:

```
import limencello from ../img/limoncello.png
```

And then use it in `img tag` like below

```
<img src={limencello} />
```

Answer (score 0):

its thinking that "imgsrc": "../img/limoncello.png" is a module
to use images you can import it at the top of the file and then use it
like **import image from location** and image must be in src folder